# libreoffice calc: text labels on y-axis of a chart

Tags: graph, charts, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am making a bar graph of survey results for my dissertation in libreoffice calc. the X axis is experimental conditions, and the y axis is average question response on a 0-4 scale. I would like to replace the 0-4 with text (0= "Very bad" 4= "Very good"). Is there a way to replace these numerical values in the y-axis with that text?

I've gone through the options in "Format --> Y-Axis" and dont see any options.

Here is the example of the chart where I would like to have text labels on the y-axis [examplechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4neX.png)

here are the data from the chart above:

Performance Rating
Control  (n=8,593) 1.15
Ask  (n=4,261)  1.13
Tell  (n=4,326) 1.16 ``

Comment: Could you provide some data ?

Comment: yes @pnorton thanks! added the data above that are the ones used int he example chart.

Comment: Hi Tara Nice chart. You could change the scale a little to give your chart the emphasise it deserves. The chart looks great as it is. This may help you Ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable

Comment: @pnorton thanks, for a number of reasons the scale of the chart is needed as is. Any idea on how to add the text labels to the y-axis?